# Integer overflow on ExecuteNonQuery() on Release, not Debug (C#)

Tags: c#, odbc, overflow

Whenever I run the program in debug it works perfectly, however, once I turn it into Release and run it, I get an overflow from an ExecuteNonQuery().
The query is very short and it's a simple update that works just fine if I run it manually in the DBMS or while in Debug mode, but for some reason it returns an overflow in release mode (note: I'm not even storing the value anywhere, so the overflow isn't caused by a variable but by the function itself)

Thanks in advance!

Code: Sorry, I completely forgot about it!

```
App.Comando.CommandText = "UPDATE META3.Paramet SET ConPCO = " 
      + numpcoGen.ToString().Replace(",",".") 
      + " WHERE CodEmp = 1 AND Ano =  " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

App.Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Stack trace: (Unfortunately the ODBC driver is in Spanish, even though the IDE and everything else is in English...)

> Exception Exception thrown: 'System.OverflowException' in System.Data.dll ("La operación aritmética ha provocado un desbordamiento.") System.OverflowException

Please note that I know that concatenation is bad practice, however it requires no user input and it's the way the manager wants it.

The ExecuteNonQuery() affects one row (manually) - while in release, if I attach a debugger, it returns -1 (still shouldn't be a problem, imo) and the field IS modified in the DB.

If I put the ExecuteNonQuery() as a watch and reevaluate it, it throws the same exception.

Comment: Error message / stack trace?

Comment: @stuartd You're completely right, my bad! Added them.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Added, the stack trace comes afterward but I know for sure it happens in the ExecuteNonQuery(), it returns -1 and if I run it manually via the Watch, it says it generated an exception.

Comment: My guess would be that the Problem is related to the ',' / '.' in the number. I think you have a different locale setting. What type is the ConPCO column? Have you tried logging the Executed SQL (Print to file or to messagebox)? Is it the same for release / debug?

Comment: @ThomasVoß it's the same Query, I made sure of it, I executed it manually on the DBMS and worked perfectly. I had to add the replace, because of that. The DB field is decimal, the locale uses a comma, while the db uses a dot.

Comment: curious, what happens when you switch to Release, right click on the project file inside the solution explorer select `Properties`, `Build` and uncheck `Optimize code` and try to run your program then?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler removed Optimized Code, recompilied and the same thing happens. I had removed the Optimize code in the Debug section, didn't think to do the same on Release, good idea, but it didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by something totally different: concurrency. `App.Commando` seems to be something static - different threads may overwrite its contents. 
Look at the documentation from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0sdddxt(v=vs.100).aspx :

`For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.`

Since you report a return value of `-1`, it cannot be the return value for the UPDATE query you showed us. Hence I suggest a multi-threading problem as the cause.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the program is programmed iteratively, single threaded. Besides, when I have ExecuteNonQuery() as a watch, App.Comando is the update command. Thanks for the suggestion, though.